# Bootstrap typescript angularjs change lines

Tags: css, angularjs, typescript, twitter-bootstrap

[image]I have four photos in one row. When the row is complete, I pass to another row and when it is full I pass to a third row, but this is incomplete. How can I tell to angular it is time to change line or the row is imcompelete and to close the row? I am using the grid of bootstrap3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it need to be done programmatically? I would just put them all in one row, and handle the items per row issue in CSS with width percentages (25%) with float left

Comment: Then you'll need nested ng-repeats.

Outer repeat is for rows, which is number of items / 4.

Inner repeats 4 items. Item to show is item[rowIndex*itemIndex]. Don't forget to check if an item of that index exists, or you'll get undefined

Comment: I dont understart the ideia in aglar 2 ngrepeat becames ngFO, can you illustrate a example please

Comment: Here's a plunker example of what I meant: 

https://plnkr.co/edit/x11nuld1PmSTO4mLIjmG?p=preview

Comment: send the link please

Comment: sorry- i fixed the link

Comment: Can you do in angular js 2?

Comment: I need the class row, there any way  add to your code?